# Turn on gzip on nginx, upstream (nodejs) or both?

Tags: node.js, compression

I have an application running behind a proxy, both on the same machine. Which approach is more suited regarding compression, while preserving reasonable performance.

- turn on compression at the application level (which happens to be in nodejs)
- leave it out to the proxy (which is nginx)

Comment: Questions having the phrase "what/which is better" in them generally don't make very good questions for this site, because we don't know what "better" means to you.  We prefer that you describe the *specific problem* you're trying to solve.

Comment: Means ? Well the question says "performanc"e

Comment: The question says "compression *and* performance;" to optimize one, you often have to sacrifice the other.

Comment: Ok how come people answered my unclear question, and gave a clear answer. And other faved the question. And yes, the question says compression AND performance. Life is not black or white, you can doze both.

Comment: I'm allergic to any question containing the words "which is better?"  We generally don't know the answer to that, unless you can tell us in some way what you mean by "better."

Comment: It's exactly because of that "which is better" that I haven't posted my question to ServerFault or even Stackoverflow. programmers.se's description says "Q&A for professional programmers interested in *conceptual questions*"

Comment: Well, now you know.

Comment: Now I know what ?

Comment: That poorly-specified questions are not welcome here either, regardless of their supposed "conceptual" character.  Real questions have answers, not opinions.

Comment: Poor ? Man come on, an app, a proxy and compression. You need a diagram?

Comment: Also, refrain from using "Edit" in your questions.  Every post has a detailed edit history that anyone can review.

Comment: You know what I mean.  "Which is better?"

Comment: You could edit the question and remove the which is better then !

Comment: Then it wouldn't even be a question.

Comment: Yes. Of course. You are right.

Comment: Anyway, kdgregory is right; this is probably a better question for ServerFault.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258433/839601

Comment: @RobertHarvey Then just let it be answered with what is better in every possible metric. And what? “to optimize one, you often have to sacrifice the other.”? Did you even read the question? **There’s no trade-offs** in “On which should I perform compression for the best performance, NGINX or Node.js?” **because no one of them does more compression than the other.** The OP mentioned nothing about tweaking the compression level here and there; identical compression levels are assumed by the context and anyone with basic reading comprehension would get that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The OP is asking about how performing compression in NGINX and Node.js are different **_considering their (and the whole tech stack’s) structural natures_** that it makes going for one of them suboptimal. How can answers to such a question be opinionated? Are trade-offs involved in this question? **No.** Does it require benchmarks to explain? **No.** This question is clear enough to be understood by anyone with basic reading comprehension that it can’t be further clarified. Do you close every question that contains “which?” You’re not a dumb linter, are you?

Comment: @КонстантинВан: You're responding to a post that is nearly six years old.  There's nothing more to see here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While this is probably a better question for ServerFault, I believe there is a clear answer: do compression on nginx.

There are a couple of reasons for this:

- Compression is moderately CPU-intensive, and Node is single-threaded. Therefore, compression in node will potentially reduce the total number of requests a single server is able to handle.
- You will almost certainly use nginx to serve static assets such as JavaScript, CSS, images, and static HTML. Which you will want to compress. So why not compress everything that goes through nginx, including forwarded traffic?

As for both: that's just wasted CPU.

Comment: Thanks for the answer 
PS: the third option was for fun :)

Comment: This answer is just sort of wrong. For one, you do not want to compress everything that goes through; images come to mind. Secondly, Node.js uses a reactor pattern and IO is async, like gzip. Nginx uses the same event loop and thread pooling pattern. It makes very little practical difference where it happens.

Comment: @Maletor - compression requires CPU, regardless of where it happens. If your Node server is spending its CPU doing compression, it doesn't have that CPU for other purposes. In any non-trivial web application, you want to offload as much as you can from the machines that are actually doing work. A front-end server is the standard solution to this.

Comment: Absolutely. But that prerequisites you have Nginx on another server. If it's on the same server I would imagine the end result would be of negligible difference; NGINX is superior in managing concurrency and would probably be slightly faster.

Comment: A lot more opinions also on this reddit thread, interestingly they lean more towards letting node handle it - https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/3l1n5h/noobis_it_better_to_enable_compression_in/

Answer (score 3):

Presuming your nginx server fronting node is proximate to said node server you get just about nothing out of using things like compression between the two. You've got plenty of bandwidth between the two, why waste CPU saving it? Moreover, if you are doing any rewrites in nginx it gets ugly as nginx has to unzip the contents, replace, and re-zip. If it lets ya do it at all.